# How to create a default response using dialogflow.v2beta1

Tags: java, kotlin, dialogflow-es

I have the following (kotlin) code:

```
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.*

val project = "my-super-agent"

val trainingPhraseBuilder = Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part.newBuilder()
trainingPhraseBuilder.text = "Tell me about the product."
val trainingPhrasePart = trainingPhraseBuilder.build()
println(trainingPhrasePart)

var i = with(Intent.newBuilder()) {
    displayName = "My First Built Intent"
    addTrainingPhrases(Intent.TrainingPhrase.newBuilder().addAllParts(listOf(trainingPhrasePart)))
    val message =
        with(addMessagesBuilder()) {
            basicCardBuilder.setFormattedText("It is amazing. Truly it is.")
            build()
        }
    build()
}
```

and then of course

```
IntentsClient.create().use({ intentsClient ->

    val intrequest = CreateIntentRequest.newBuilder()
        .setParent("projects/$project/agent")
        .setIntent(i)
        .build()

    val response1 = intentsClient.createIntent(intrequest)

})
```

but for the life of me I can't figure out how to create a trivial entry in this section: [image]

The basic cards appear in the Google Assistant section (obviously).

What am I missing in order to create default simple default responses? If you are thinking "oh that's easy - it's ...." then yes you are correct - it is simple I just can't find it.

FWIW. Some of my (not working) attempts look like:

```
var sr = Intent.Message.SimpleResponse.newBuilder()
sr.setDisplayText("Pleeeeaaaassssseeee")
val simpleReponseMessage = sr.build()

addMessagesBuilder()
.simpleResponsesBuilder
.addSimpleResponses(simpleReponseMessage)
.build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 addMessagesBuilder().setPlatform(Intent.Message.Platform.PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED).setText(Intent.Message.Text.newBuilder().addText("ffs")).build()
```

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't done it myself, I am referring to the REST API and found the [Intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#resource-intent) has a [Message](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#message) type which can be a collection responses.

The message should have a field called [SimpleResponses](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#simpleresponses), which is an array of [SimpleResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#simpleresponse) objects.

This should update the console. It looks like they appear in *Google Assistant* because the Message type has an optional field of type [Platform](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#Platform). I'm not sure what the default value is, but would `PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED` place it in the right section?

The implementation would look similar to (using the [dialogflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) package):

```
const intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient();
const parent = intentsClient.projectAgentPath(projectId);
const dfIntent = {
  // Put other values in here
  // ...
  messages: [{
    platform: 'PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED',
    text: [ 'Default message' ]
  }]
}
// Or execute updateIntent if it already exists
const creationResponse = await intentsClient.createIntent({
  parent,
  languageCode: 'en',
  intent: dfIntent
})
```

I haven't tested the behavior of the snippet, but this should add a generic text response.

Comment: Sure - but I can't figure out how to use the API in order to make this happen.. Do you have the line of code?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a Node.js snippet of the code you'd generally need to implement. I think, based on reading the docs, that many response types are only used in the Google Assistant section, such as simpleResponses. The text field should be generic.

Comment: Thanks Nick - but I need a java / kotlin solution as this needs to integrate with the rest of the platform, and that requires the `builder` and `SimpleResponse.newBuilder()` stuff...

Comment: If you understand the snippet above, you should be able to adjust the logic to fit your language of choice

Comment: Seems like you can do `addMessagesBuilder().setPlatform(...).addText(...).build()`

Comment: There is no `addText()` after `setPlatform()`